# Grails RESTful API Plugin - wrong service siginiture

Tags: rest, grails, service

I am trying to use Restful API plugin ([Restful API plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/restful-api)). (using Grails 2.3.8, Groovy 2.1)

As stated in documentation I created a Grails service that implements [RestfulServiceAdapter](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/restfulapi/restful-api/master/src/groovy/net/hedtech/restfulapi/RestfulServiceAdapter.groovy).

```
import net.hedtech.restfulapi.RestfulServiceAdapter
import com.game.trivia.Question
@Transactional
class QuestionService implements RestfulServiceAdapter {
    @Override
    public Object list(def service, Map params) throws Throwable{
        List Q = Question.list(params)

        return Q;
    }
.  
.  
.
```

When trying to access the service: `http://localhost:8080/test_triv/api/questions`

I received following exception:

```
    {"errors":[{"type":"general",
    "errorMessage":"No signature of method: test_triv.QuestionService.list() is applicable for argument types:
     (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsParameterMap) values:
     [[pluralizedResourceName:questions, action:[...], ...]]\nPossible solutions: list(java.lang.Object, java.util.Map), 
    is(java.lang.Object), wait(), find(), wait(long), with(groovy.lang.Closure)"}]}
```

So I implemented another list method (which is not part of the interface):

```
public Object list(Map params) throws Throwable {
            List Q = Question.list(params)
            return Q;
        }
```

Which works ok.

Am I doing something wrong?
Do I implement the correct interface?
Do I have to expose a service for each domain or there is any way to use an existing controller instead of a service?
Creating new service is a big overhead! I already have controllers for all domains.

Answer (score 0):

Just got reply on this issue from Charlie (The pludin developer):

Our documentation should be clearer in this area, so I'll take an action to look at improving it.

You should not implement the RestfulServiceAdapter within a service, but implement and register an adapter that implements this interface if you need to adapt an existing service that does not provide the expected methods.

Since you are writing a new service, you can just expose the required methods (you don't need to implement any interface). Note the contract is essentially the same as the adapter interface, without the 'service' argument that represents the service to which the adapter would delegate.

To avoid needing an adapter, a service should expose these methods:

```
def list( Map params ) throws Throwable { ... }

def count( Map params ) throws Throwable { ... }

def show( Map params ) throws Throwable { ... }

def create( Map content, Map params ) throws Throwable { ... }

def update( def id, Map content, Map params ) throws Throwable { ... }

void delete( def id, Map content, Map params ) throws Throwable { ... }
```

The controller is intended to delegate to a service that contains business logic, and it cannot delegate to another controller.  Our expectation is the RestfulApiController and other controllers within an application would share services (e.g., a ThingController and the RESTfulApiController could both use the same ThingService so that business logic is not duplicated).